# Prometheus Alertmanager notification template periodical buggy output

Tags: go-templates, prometheus-alertmanager

I'm using kube-prometheus-stack alertmanager (0.25) notification template to send alerts to opsgenie. Grouping is disabled for alertmanager. All alerts have following label: "k8sCluster: dev", I have following template:

```golang
{{ define "__subject" }}
{{- range .Alerts.Firing }}
[{{ .Labels.k8sCluster | title }}]: {{ .Annotations.description }}
{{- end }}
{{ end }}

{{ define "__source" }}{{ range .Alerts.Firing }}{{ .Labels.k8sCluster | title }}{{ end }}{{ end }}

{{ define "__description" }} 
{{ range .Alerts.Firing }}
- **Problem started at** {{ .StartsAt.Format "15:04:05" }} on {{ .StartsAt.Format "02.01.2006" }}
- **Problem name**: {{ .Annotations.summary }}
- **Problem description**: {{ .Annotations.description }}
- **Severity**: {{ .Labels.severity }}
{{- if .Labels.environment }}
- **Environment**: {{ .Labels.environment }}
{{- end }}
{{- if .Labels.env }}
- **Environment**: {{ .Labels.env }}
{{- end }}
{{- if .Labels.namespace }}
- **Namespace**: {{ .Labels.namespace }}
{{- end }}
{{- if .Labels.deployment }}
- **Deployment**: {{ .Labels.deployment }}
{{- end }}
{{- if .Labels.pod }}
- **Pod**: {{ .Labels.pod }}
{{- end }}
{{ end }}
{{ end }}

{{ define "opsgenie.default.tags" }}
Environment:
{{- range .Alerts.Firing -}}
{{- if match "test-.*" .Labels.namespace -}}
Test
{{- else if eq "test2-.*" .Labels.namespace -}}
Test2
{{- else -}}
{{ .Labels.k8sCluster | title }}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
{{ end }}

{{ define "opsgenie.default.message" }}{{ template "__subject" . }}{{ end }}
{{ define "opsgenie.default.description" }}{{ template "__description" . }}{{ end }}
{{ define "opsgenie.default.source" }}{{ template "__source" . }}{{ end }}
```

So I noticed that when there are couple of alerts flapping\firing simultaneously the output in opsgenie for the `{{ .Labels.k8sCluster | title }}` can have some gibberish results like:

```
Example alert1:
#967 Prometheus [���]: Pod test-alert/faulty-ubuntu-6cf8c46d46-qdrdt (faulty-ubuntu) restarted 1.20 times over last minute.
Source: EVv

Example alert2:
#966 Prometheus [DDv]: Pod test-alert/faulty-ubuntu-6cf8c46d46-mngn8 (faulty-ubuntu) restarted 1.20 times over last minute.
Source is missing for this one

Example alert3:
#958 Prometheus [Dv�]: Pod test-alert/faulty-ubuntu-6cf8c46d46-6ktdl (faulty-ubuntu) restarted 1.20 times over last minute.
Source: Dev
```

So different fields(subject, source) have different results after applying `{{ .Labels.k8sCluster | title }}` to "dev"

Those "???" are not displayed in opsgenie, but after that displayed as "???" in MsTeams as per alert route.

I tried removing title from `{{ .Labels.k8sCluster | title }}` and flooding alertmanager with alerts - everything is fine.

I tried removing templating completely and just setting this as "Dev" and flooding alertmanager with alerts - everything is fine.